# Code generated with openapi generator fails in gradle but not with maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

I am migrating an open API specification project from maven to gradle. However, Gradle build fails with this error while maven works without error.

```
/Users/skgupta/git-repos/openapi-changes/mycompany-service/specification/build/generate-resources/main/src/main/java/com/mycompany/config/OpenAPIDocumentationConfig.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.paths.RelativePathProvider;
                                               ^
  symbol:   class RelativePathProvider
  location: package springfox.documentation.spring.web.paths
/Users/skgupta/git-repos/openapi-changes/mycompany-service/specification/build/generate-resources/main/src/main/java/com/mycompany//config/OpenAPIDocumentationConfig.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
    class BasePathAwareRelativePathProvider extends RelativePathProvider {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   class RelativePathProvider
  location: class OpenAPIDocumentationConfig
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mycompany-specification:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is the `build.gradle` file content

```
  id 'org.openapi.generator'
}
dependencies {
  implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.3"
  implementation "jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:2.2.3"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:${jackson_version}"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:${jackson_version}"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:${jackson_version}"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:${jackson_version}"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:${jackson_version}"
  implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:${jackson_version}"
  implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:+"
  implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:+"
  implementation "javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:${springfox_version}"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:${springfox_version}"
  implementation "io.springfox:springfox-oas:${springfox_version}"
  implementation "org.openapitools:jackson-databind-nullable:${jackson_databind_nullable}"
  runtimeOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20"
}

openApiGenerate {
  inputSpec = project.file('src/main/resources/api_spec.yaml').path
  generatorName = 'spring'
  apiPackage = 'com.mycompnay.api'
  modelPackage = 'com.mycompany.model'
  invokerPackage = 'com.mycompany.invoker'
  modelNameSuffix = 'DTO'
  modelNamePrefix = 'Tessell'
  //templateDirectory = project.file('src/main/resources/templates').path
  configOptions = [
    configPackage: 'com.mycompany.config',
    unhandledException: "true",
    dateLibrary: 'java8',
    delegatePattern: "true",
    hideGenerationTimestamp: "false",
    additionalModelTypeAnnotations: ';@lombok.Builder;@lombok.AllArgsConstructor;@lombok.NoArgsConstructor;@lombok.Setter;@lombok.Getter'
  ]
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs += [openApiGenerate.outputDir]
compileJava.dependsOn('openApiGenerate')
```

content of `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mycompany-specification</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>mycompany-specfication</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
        <jackson-version>2.11.4</jackson-version>
        <jackson-databind-nullable>0.2.1</jackson-databind-nullable>
        <springfox-version>3.0.0</springfox-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-oas</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson-databind-nullable}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycompany-common-m2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>mycompany-common-m2-pojo</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api_spec.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <apiPackage>com.mycompany.api</apiPackage>
                            <modelPackage>com.mycompany.model</modelPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>com.mycompany.invoker</invokerPackage>
                            <modelNameSuffix>DTO</modelNameSuffix>
                            <modelNamePrefix>Tessell</modelNamePrefix>
                            <templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/templates</templateDirectory>
                            <configOptions>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>true</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                                <configPackage>com.mycompany.config</configPackage>
                                <unhandledException>true</unhandledException>
                                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                                <hideGenerationTimestamp>false</hideGenerationTimestamp>
                                <additionalModelTypeAnnotations>;@Builder;@AllArgsConstructor;@NoArgsConstructor;@Setter;@Getter</additionalModelTypeAnnotations>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Content of `gradle.properties`

```
jackson_databind_nullable=0.2.1
springfox_version=3.0.0
```

Comment: OpenAPI does not yet support Springfox 3.0.0, so the Gradle failure is expected (the referenced class `RelativePathProvider` has been replaced with `DefaultPathProvider`). I think you have to downgrade to 2.9.2, though I can't say how you got it working in Maven in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @BjørnVester; 

I was missing `templateDir` config, after fixing that, it worked with 3.0.0

Comment: Hi @SundeepGupta could you please elaborate more about how you were solving the issue in using Springfox 3.0.0 ? thank you so much